# NLog Elasticsearch integration @timestamp works wrong(2 hours early) in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, nlog

I am sending logs from NLog to ElasticSearch. So , when I saw in ElasticSearch part I see that @timestamp shows wrong , it shows 2 hours early.

I saw default `@timestamp` working wrongs, I added my time in NLog.config, but when I check Elasticsearch then my time now is working fine but it seems text format , I expected date format.

In NLog.config file:

```
    <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="ElasticSearch"
        flushTimeout="5000">
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
          index = "logstash-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}"           
          uri = "http://localhost:9200/"
          includeAllProperties ="true">
    <field name="host" layout="${machinename}"/>
    <field name="message" layout="${message}"/>
    <field name="src" layout="${logger}"/>
    <field name="time" layout="${longdate}"/>
   </target>
  </target>
```

why time seems text format? How can I change Date format?

Is there way inside NLog.config I can change `@timestamp` field which is using default in ElasticSearch.

Comment: Elasticsearch store the dates in UTC, if you are on a timezone that is UTC + 2, the time 2019-07-04 10:00:00 will be stored as 2019-07-04 08:00:00 on Elasticsearch. Could this be your case?

Comment: @leandrojmp yes , you are absolutely correct. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Elastic stores the dates in UTC, you will need to convert the result to your timezone, if you use Kibana it does this automatically, according to the browser timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added my own field timeStamp and it works for me:

```
<field name="timeStamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffZ}"/>
```

Full target configuration:

```
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" layout="${message}"
          uri="http://x.y.z.i:9200"
          index="log-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
          documentType="logEvent">
    <field name="hostName" layout="${machinename}"/>
    <field name="timeStamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffZ}"/>
    <field name="loggerName" layout="${logger}"/>
  </target>
</target>
```

Our Elastic Search version is 7.12.0

Answer (score 0):

For ElasticSearch the date should be UTC,

so use

```
${longdate:universalTime=true}
```